# Complexity of 2D-Minkowski sum of non-convex polygons

Tags: computational-complexity, convex-polytopes, polygons

I have read that the complexity of computing the Minkowski-Sum of $2$ non-convex polygons (through convex decomposition) is $O(m^2 n^2)$, where $m$ and $n$ is the number of vertices of each polygon. How can we prove this? I managed to prove that convex + convex has complexity $O(m+n)$ and convex + non-convex is $O(mn)$, but I got stuck on the last case. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

See Eli Fogel's [slides.](http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/courses/algorithmic-robotics/spring-2011/slides/ms.pdf) and be enlightened.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Igor's link with a paper citation:

> Agarwal, Pankaj K., Eyal Flato, and Dan Halperin. "Polygon decomposition for efficient construction of Minkowski sums." *Computational Geometry* 21, no. 1-2 (2002): 39-61.
>
> ---
>
> [image: Fig2]

---